# Write JSON data to file using AJAX post + node / express

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, node.js, express

I just started learning and experimenting with Node.js (first time dealing with AJAX, JSON and server-side), and I want to post the contents of a simple form to a file in my directory in JSON format using AJAX and a Node / Express server. I'm currently getting a `POST http://localhost:3000/server.js 404 (Not Found)` or `POST http://localhost:3000/add-tasks 500 (Internal Server Error)` error each time I try to post the form's contents (see questions at bottom for more details).

Here's the directory structure:

[image]

Here's my HTML *(filename: index.html)*:

```
<div>
  <label for="important">Important?</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="important" name="important">
 </div>
 <div>
   <label for="urgent">Urgent?</label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="urgent" name="urgent">
 </div>
 <button type="button" id="submitToDo">
  Add
 </button>
</div>
```

Here's the client-side JS *(filename: main.js)*:

```
$( document ).ready( function () { 

  var userTask = $( "#task" ).val();
  var userImportant = $( "#important" ).prop( "checked" );
  var userUrgent = $( "#urgent" ).prop( "checked" );

  var toDo = {
    task: userTask,
    important: userImportant,
    urgent: userUrgent,
  };

  $( "#submitToDo" ).on("click", function() {
    $.post("/server.js", toDo);
  });

});
```

Here's the server-side JS, which I mostly borrowed from a tutorial, so I'm not sure if it's all necessary *(filename: server.js)*:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var fs = require("fs");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use(express.static("./public"));

app.post("/add-tasks", function(req, res) {
  fs.write("tasks.json", "JSON", req.body);
});

app.listen(3000);

console.log("Express is running on port 3000");
```

Few questions I've had while trying to get this to work:

- What path / URL should I be putting for `$.post` and `app.post`? I get a 500 error when I put `/add-tasks` for the `$.post` and I get a 404 when it's `/server.js`.
- Is `fs.write` the method I should be using to add the JSON to my *tasks.json* file?

Comment: [fs.write documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_write_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback)

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. There appear to have been two issues:

1. The server.js file was supposed to be named app.js.
2. I was using the `fs.write` method improperly and should've been using `fs.writeFile`.